# Test if Block is rendered in EMail or in Page (by PHP code)

Tags: blocks, email-templates, render

How is it possible to test whether a custom block (`extends Mage_Core_Block_Template`) is rendered in a HTML page or rendered in an email (transactional email template)? I want to do this in the PHP code of the block (in my case in `recentproducts.phtml`). It should look like

```
// recentproducts.phtml
if ($this->rendered_in() == 'page')
    echo('Foo.');
elseif ($this->rendered_in() == 'email')
    echo('Bar.');
```

The block
`{{block someparam="some data" type="recentproducts/recentproducts" name="recentproducts_recentproducts" template="recentproducts/recentproducts.phtml"}}`
is used in at CMS -> Static Blocks. I followed the tutorial [Custom Block Development in Magento](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-block-development-in-magento--cms-23104).

Magento Version 1.9.1.1

Comment: Probably need to be more specific. Do you see the block? Then it's been rendered.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Test Which Template is called in HTML**

Steps to get Template Path Hints:

Login to Magento Admin panel

1. Go to `System->Configuration`. The Template Path and Block name will
   only appear for current website. So change the Current Configuration
   Scope to `Main Website`.
2. Go to the Advanced section and click on
   Developers. Expand the Debug tab. Set the Template Path Hints to
   `Yes`. Click on `Save Configuration` button.
3. Open Magento user panel
   and see the template path hints. It shows each file where the page
   element is located in.

This will tell you which block is called. [More info](http://insync.co.in/how-to-enable-template-path-and-block-name-hints-in-magento-commerce/).

Comment: Thanks, good to know. But this was not the question. I’m updating the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no out of the box way of checking if you are in a page environment or in an email environment.
But you can specify this from your layout files or from your e-mail configuration.
For example if you have this code in the layout file that displays your block

```
<block type="type/here" template="template/here.phtml" name="some.name" />
```

you can transform it to this:

```
<block type="type/here" template="template/here.phtml" name="some.name">
    <action method="setRenderedIn"><rendered>page</rendered></action>
</block>
```

then you will be able to access this in the block or template:

```
$this->getRenderedIn();
```

This should return `page` if you used the xml above.

And if you render it in an email template like

```
{{block type="type/here" template="template/here.phtml"}}
```

you can transform it into

```
{{block type="type/here" template="template/here.phtml" rendered_in="email"}}
```

Again you will be able to access this value in the block or template using

```
$this->getRenderedIn();
```

In this case it should return `email`.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial that you pointed out is excellent and I see codes and concepts are clear except for the template declaration part. `Envato_Recentproducts` extension uses a template `recentproducts.phtml` which is instructed to create at `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/recentproducts/recentproducts.phtml`.

But actually, the best practices says, we should place our template in the current active package theme directory. That means, the path will look like this (in general).

```
app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/recentproducts/recentproducts.phtml
```

So in order to make the above specified template should work, it is required that, you active package-theme of your current store should be `default/default` and most probably this would not be the case.

So put your template in your active package-theme directory or put it in `base/default` directory. Magento is smart enough to pick your template from `base/default` package-theme directory, if it couldn't find your template file inside your current package-theme directly. ie the file path that you should will look like this.

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/recentproducts/recentproducts.phtml
```

---

***Note:*** Dont forget to clear the cache after all changes made.

Comment: You are right. I already put `recentproducts.phtml` in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/recentproducts/`. But this was not the question. I’m updating the question to be more specific.